# make style overwrite style of #wrapper

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble inputting an animated image slider that transitions using perspective, but due to the parallax effect that already uses a perspective rule it completely messes up the image slider.

Here is the code that I am working with. As you can see the wrapper obviously encases all of the elements.

```html
    <main id="wrapper" id="home">
      <section class="section parallax bg1">
        <img class="swift_design_title" src="images/swift_design_title.png" alt="swift_design_title.png">
        <div class="nav">
          <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="#home">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
       </section>
          <section class="section static" id="about">
            <img src="images/fg_img_one.png" alt="fg_img_one.png" style="width:100%;">
          </section>
            <section class="section parallax bg2">
            </section>
              <section id="slider">
                <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s1">
                <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s2">
                <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s3" checked>
                <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s4">
                <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s5">
                <label for="s1" id="slide1"></label>
                <label for="s2" id="slide2"></label>
                <label for="s3" id="slide3"></label>
                <label for="s4" id="slide4"></label>
                <label for="s5" id="slide5"></label>
              </section>
    </main>
```

This is the CSS, as you can see the wrapper overwrites the perspective element that the slider uses, but I need them both to be active at once.

```css
.wrapper {
  /* The height needs to be set to a fixed value for the effect to work.
   * 100vh is the full height of the viewport. */
  height: 100vh;
  /* The scaling of the images would add a horizontal scrollbar, so disable x overflow. */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* Enable scrolling on the page. */
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Set the perspective to 2px. This is essentailly the simulated distance from the viewport to transformed objects.*/
  perspective: 3px;
}

#slider {
  height: 35vw;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#slider label {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
}
```

Is there a way I can make the wrapper apply to the slider section but allow for the slider to have its own perspective set inside the section?

Thanks!
- Ben

Comment: have you tried adding `!important`?

Comment: Where and how would I add that? @kapitan

Comment: perspective: 1000px !important;

Comment: Didn't seem to work :/ - have developed the website using wordpress with the divibuilder plugin and added the code modules necessary to get the look I was going for

still incomplete but if you're interested this is what it looks like - swiftgraphicdesign.com